# How to get the relative complement of a boolean numpy array and another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, logical-operators

Let's say I have two numpy arrays:

```
>>> v1
array([ True, False, False, False,  True])
>>> v2
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

I'm trying to retrieve an array that has the same length (5) and contains `True` in each position where `v1==True AND v2==False`. That would be:

```
array([True, False,  False,  False,  False])
```

Is there a quick way in numpy, something like `logical_not()` but considering `v1` as the reference and `v2` as the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the right [`bitwise operators`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
v1 & ~v2
# array([ True, False, False, False, False])
```

Answer (score 3):

For boolean values, logical and bitwise operations are the same. It is therefore quite idiomatic to write

```
v1 & ~v2
```

However, this is a bitwise operation, and produces a potentially unnecessary temp array. You can not write `v1 and not v2` as much as you'd like to because python expects to convert the inputs to single boolean values. Instead, you have to call the [`logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [`logical_not`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) ufuncs:

```
np.logical_and(v1, np.logical_not(v2))
```

The nice thing is that you can avoid the temp array, or even write directly to a buffer of your choice:

```
result = np.empty_like(v1)
np.logical_not(v2, out=result)
np.logical_and(v1, result, out=result)
```

You can even do the whole thing in-place (in `v2`):

```
np.logical_and(v1, np.logical_not(v2, out=v2), out=v2)
```

Comment: So you avoid copying with `out=result`?

Comment: @yatu. You avoid a separate output array from the "not" operation by using the same output buffer for all the operations.

Comment: I see, so no additional mem allocation this way, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of *bitwise* operators here:

```
>>> v1 & ~v2
array([ True, False, False, False, False])
```